# Can't clone Repo when using SOCKS5 Proxy

Tags: git, ssh, socks

I'm sitting behind a firewall and need to configure my git-config, so that it'll take my `socks5`-proxy. I tried several methods already, but i still end up with:

```
$ git clone git@my-gitlab.de:username/testprojekt.git
Cloning into 'testprojekt'...
ssh: connect to host my-gitlab port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I had the same issue earlier when I used `putty`, but I was able to store my proxy-settings there and the connection worked afterwards. 
I can clone repos via `https`, but I really want to make us of `SSH`.

Things I tried, which didn't work:

```
git config --global http.proxy socks5://myProxy:1080
git config --global http.proxy socks://myProxy:1080
```

After using

```
$ git config --get http.proxy
```

I get the correct output:

```
socks5://myProxy:1080
```

but still the same error as you can tell. I'm using **Git for windows**

**Edit:**

```
$ ssh -T git@myGitlab.de
```

already times out

This is one of the ressources I tried to follow to solve this problem:
https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765

Answer (score 1):

You've configured `http.proxy` but's trying to connect through it with `ssh://` protocol. That of course meaningless.

You need to configure `ssh` to use socks proxy. See https://superuser.com/questions/454210/how-can-i-use-ssh-with-a-socks-5-proxy for example.

```
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x myProxy:1080 %h %p
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but `nc` is netcat, isn't it? Does this work for windows as well? Thanks so far though! 
Just checked: `/usr/bin/nc: no suche file or directory` - With what do I have to replace this nc?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1225467 recommends https://nmap.org/ncat/. `ProxyCommand ncat --proxy hostToYourProxy:1080 %h %p`